# Can no longer get into Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to do some React Native development for Android.

In the past I've been able to run and use a couple Android Emulators on my machine.  Now, when I start the emulators I see them launch successfully, but I don't see them appear on my screen:

[image]

I'm running

```
Edition Windows 11 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎10/‎5/‎2022
OS build    22621.1105
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22638.1000.0
```

and

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
```

How can I view the running emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I clicked this tab:
[image]

The Emulator would appear as a tiny (maybe 20 x 20 pixels) window on my other monitor.  I then was able to make the window bigger and use it.